# Trying to join tables using ARRAY_CONTAINS yields never-ending run

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have three tables: "USERS", "COMPANIES" and "FILES", where each USER has a variant column named: "COMAPNY_IDS" that is a simple array that matches records in the "COMPANIES" table.

Each FILE belongs to a single COMPANY via its "COMPANY_ID" field.

We would like to join each USER with every one of the FILEs that its connected to via any of the COMPANIES its associated to.

This naive solution:

```
SELECT u._id as user_id, z._id as file_id, z.SENT_ON 
FROM users u, 
LATERAL (SELECT f._id, f.SENT_ON 
from FILES f 
where ( ARRAY_CONTAINS(TO_VARIANT(f.COMPANY_ID), TO_ARRAY(u.COMPANY_IDS)))) z
```

Takes forever and never finishes.

A more convoluted solution that avoids the "ARRAY_CONTAINS" function - finishes in a second and a half:

```
SELECT u._id as user_id, max(files.sent_on) 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    select *
    FROM companies c,
    lateral (select  flt.value as cid , us._id as uid 
            from users us,
            lateral flatten ( company_ids) as flt
            where cid = c._id) ccc

            ) x on (x.uid = u._id)
   LEFT JOIN files
       on x.cid = files.company_id
    GROUP BY u._id
```

Is there something preventing ARRAY_CONTAINS from being used properly in "ON" clauses or as part of the "WHERE" clause of correlated lateral sub-queries?

Comment: A generally rule of SQL is "never use a function in a WHERE clause" and an ON is a where clause.. Then if you grok the Snowflake is a giant map/reduce like system, you will observe things where you build data A and data B and join the (just like you do in you "convoluted" example) it performs this three simple steps very fast. Over the 4 years I have been using snowflake, big-dump SQL nearly always outperforms terse clever SQL.

Comment: What does the query profile look like?  Is there a join step that exploding?  How much pruning is occurring?